# Function to switch the order of a first and last name

Tags: python, function, loops, reverse

This is what I am going for. I think I can use the `len` function, but I can't find anything to iterate over each item rather than just reversing the order of the list.

Input List: `['Tony Hawk', 'Rose Will', 'Humpty Dumpty', 'Jill Mark']`

Output List: `['Hawk Tony', 'Will Rose', 'Dumpty Humpty', 'Mark Jill']`

Comment: Explain, in plain English words, how you would solve the problem step by step.

Comment: I need to reverse the order of the first name and the last name. So the input for example, being 'Tony Hawk' should have an output of 'Hawk Tony'

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem description perfectly. You need to break it down into smaller steps in order to solve the problem. For example, when you look at `Tony Hawk`, **how do you know** that `Tony` is "the first name" and `Hawk` is "the last name"? Why isn't, for example, the first name `Tony Ha` and the last name `wk`?

Comment: You're just re-stating the requirements (what you want the outcome to be). We know those. @KarlKnechtel is asking you what steps you would take to solve the problem. Things that you, as a programmer, would do. Like iterate over the names in the list, split them on the space character, swap the first and last values, rejoin them with a space. Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

For each element in the list, split on a space, reverse, then join back on space:

```py
def reverse_names(l):
    return [" ".join(reversed(x.split(" "))) for x in l]

print(reverse_names(['Tony Hawk', 'Rose Will', 'Humpty Dumpty', 'Jill Mark']))
# ['Hawk Tony', 'Will Rose', 'Dumpty Humpty', 'Mark Jill']
```

Comment: thank you so much!! this worked perfectly. for whatever reason, when I was trying to run the reverse function, it would not recognize it, I'm not sure what I did wrong. thank you again

Comment: The key is that this is reversing each element, not the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following for loop:

```
result = []
for first_name, last_name in map(str.split, lst):
    result.append(last_name + " " + first_name)
```

Or the *equivalent* [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = ['Tony Hawk', 'Rose Will', 'Humpty Dumpty', 'Jill Mark']
result = [f'{last_name} {first_name}' for first_name, last_name in map(str.split, lst)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Hawk Tony', 'Will Rose', 'Dumpty Humpty', 'Mark Jill']
```

The steps are:

1. Split each element by space `map(str.split, lst)` using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
2. Join the elements in reverse order `last_name + " " + first_name` (or `f'{last_name} {first_name}'`)

A third alternative is to use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of `map`, but personally I find this option more cumbersome:

```
result = [f'{last_name} {first_name}' for first_name, last_name in (s.split() for s in lst)]
```